# Stop 'Found new Hardware' popup on logon

Tags: windows, hardware-detection

I want to disable the popup telling me that Windows has found new hardware because it's annoying, and there  are no drivers for it, and disabling it causes a BSOD.

I have tried adding the following registry keys as googling around suggests but it STILL pops up...

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\windows\DeviceInstall\Settings

type: DWORD
Name: SuppressNewHWUI
Value: 1

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PlugPlay\Paramaters

type: DWORD
Name: SuppressUI
Value: 1
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Link]

How can I disable this popup?

Edit: I also think this popup is slowing down logging in, because after I click OK to logon, it hangs for a little while at the 'please wait' screen before displaying the desktop.

Unless some other driver service is causing it, I've only installed the OS and drivers yesterday, it was super fast at logging in and out/rebooting before installing drivers. I have disabled several startup services which are related to drivers.

Comment: `Paramaters` is not spelled correctly ...

Comment: ^ unless you have a skydiving mother, it's usually `parameters`

Comment: it still does not work.